# Win 8.1, Vagrant, Chef, Ubuntu, Ember-cli, ember new "npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/"

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm on Windows 8.1, with vagrant, Cheffile and everything works.

Now I'm doing:

**npm install -g ember-cli** and it's ok.

But when I do this:

**ember new sample** in vagrant folder (the same folder I can view in Windows) I receive this error:

```
version: 1.13.8
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
installing app
  create .bowerrc
  create .editorconfig
  create .ember-cli
  create .jshintrc
  create .travis.yml
  create .watchmanconfig
  create README.md
  create app/app.js
  create app/components/.gitkeep
  create app/controllers/.gitkeep
  create app/helpers/.gitkeep
  create app/index.html
  create app/models/.gitkeep
  create app/router.js
  create app/routes/.gitkeep
  create app/styles/app.css
  create app/templates/application.hbs
  create app/templates/components/.gitkeep
  create bower.json
  create config/environment.js
  create ember-cli-build.js
  create .gitignore
  create package.json
  create public/crossdomain.xml
  create public/robots.txt
  create testem.json
  create tests/.jshintrc
  create tests/helpers/resolver.js
  create tests/helpers/start-app.js
  create tests/index.html
  create tests/test-helper.js
  create tests/unit/.gitkeep
  create vendor/.gitkeep
Installing packages for tooling via npm...
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/git-repo-info/1.1.2/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/broccoli-plugin/1.2.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/hash-for-dep/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/broccoli-plugin/1.2.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/broccoli-plugin/1.2.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/hash-for-dep/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/broccoli-plugin/1.2.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/json5/0.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/source-map/0.1.32/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/defs/1.1.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/vagrant/.npm/ember-cli/1.13.8/package.tgz
EPROTO, mkdir '/vagrant/test/node_modules/ember-cli-app-version/node_modules/git-repo-version/node_modules/git-repo-info/tests/fixtures/branch-with-slashes/dot-git/refs/heads/feature/branch/with'
Error: EPROTO, mkdir '/vagrant/test/node_modules/ember-cli-app-version/node_modules/git-repo-version/node_modules/git-repo-info/tests/fixtures/branch-with-slashes/dot-git/refs/heads/feature/branch/with'
    at Error (native)
```

I'm on vagrant last box (today I do `vagrant box update`) and `node -v` says me: **v0.12.7** and `npm -v` says me: **3.3.3**

What to do?

I tried: **sudo (and not sudo) npm cache clean** and also **sudo** for every other command. Nothing, the same errors.

What it means: **`npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error`** ???

Comment: can you clean npm, `npm cache clean`

Comment: I already did it. Nothing, nothing, nothing. Also after `vagrant halt default` and again `vagrant up`.

Comment: also tried with running as `sudo npm install -g ember-cli` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing. The same errors.

Comment: May not be related but where is /vagrant mounting on your host system? Is the full path on windows more than 256 characters? It could be refusing to  make the folder on windows because the path is too long. You could test by moving it to a shorter path (e.g. c:\TEST) and mounting that folder in vagrant.

Comment: @chriskelly, the full path of my /vagrant folder on Windows is long 63 characters. Now, I will try with c:/.

Comment: Also, you could try copying your repository to a non-windows location on your VM and see if it works there. For example /tmp/myrepo which will not have any windows issue. This will at least confirm that it's a long path issue which it probably is!

Comment: Ok, @chriskelly, in C: nothing to do. The same error. Now I'll try in tmp folder.

Comment: If I run `ember new something` in /tmp folder everything works. What to do now?

Comment: I need the folder of ember new in a folder that I can use in Windows.

Comment: You could try using dedupe and see how far it gets you. Its a big issue as far as I'm concerned. May be worth reading through this official discussion for some ideas too: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6960

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90429/discussion-between-chriskelly-and-john-sam).

Comment: I tried to use ember with vagrant and has given up. There are too many problems with npm on shared filesystem. If you don't want to install linux as a second OS and if you have a powerful PC, I suggest to work inside a VM with Ubuntu as a guest OS.

Comment: I've got a very similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495587/npm-install-ember-cli-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded
Have you made any progress?